# Show all box models at once sticky

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

When I hover a DOM element in the Firefox Developer Tools, margins (yellow) and paddings (purple) are displayed on the website.

Is it possible to show these boxes for all elements at once sticky?

Comment: Sounds quite similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/44506946/432681. Though, why would you like to display them for *all* elements on the page at once? That would be a chaotic mix and you wouldn't see anything. Or do you mean all elements *matching a specific selector* or something like that?

Comment: The Web Developer plugin by Chris Pederick offers this function: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firefox DevTools provide different kinds of sticky and non-sticky highlighters.

The one you might be looking for is to highlight all elements matching a specific CSS selector, which can be toggled via the "target" icon besides each selector within the *Rules* side panel of the Inspector:

[image: Highlighter for all elements matching a specific CSS selector]

Comment: works, but it seems that resizing the window while displaying it cracks sometimes the bounds

Comment: If you see issues with the feature, you should [file a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools%3A%20Inspector), so it can get fixed.